# Induction on a sequence {$a_n$}

Tags: induction

Let a sequence be defined by $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n+4}$. Prove by inductions that $0\le a_n \le 4$ for all n.

For some reason I can't figure out what my hypothesis is? I know my base case is $a_0$ but then what do I assume? Do I isolate $a_n$? Any answers to these questions or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Your initialisation would be $a_0\le4$, which is true. The induction hypothesis is $a_n\le4$, which you then need to use to prove that $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n+4}\le4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case:

For $n=0$, we have
$a_0=1$, thus $1 \le a_0 \le 4$.

Thus the statement is true for $n=0$.

---

Induction Hypothesis:

Let the statement be true for some $n=k$, where $k\ge0$ and $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Then, we have
$$1\le a_k \le 4$$

---

Inductive Step:

Consider now for $n=k+1$. From the given recurrence relation, we have

$$a_{k+1}=\sqrt{3a_k + 4}$$
Using the inductive hypothesis,
$$1\le a_k \le 4$$
$$3\le 3a_k \le 12$$
$$7\le 3a_k + 4 \le 16$$
$$\sqrt7\le \sqrt{3a_k + 4} \le \sqrt{16}$$
$$1<\sqrt7\le \sqrt{3a_k + 4} \le 4$$
$$1\le a_{k+1} \le 4$$

Thus, whenever the statement is true for $n=k$, it is also true for $n=k+1$.

Using the principle of mathematical induction, it is true for all $n\ge0$, $n\in \mathbb Z$